# Get all WooCommerce customers paid orders with a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I need a query that returns me all the users with orders with payment approved.

I'm having a hard time finding where in the db this is stored. I found only post_status 'wc-complete', but I don't think this is the right info.

```
   SELECT a.post_status, b.meta_value FROM wp_posts a, wp_postmeta b
   WHERE a.ID = b.post_id 
   AND a.post_type = 'shop_order' 
   AND a.post_status = 'wc-completed'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Using "completed" order status for paid orders is correct

Here is a custom function with a SQL query, that will output an formatted array of User IDs with their completed orders (paid / accepted):

```
function completed_orders_ids_by_costumer_id(){

    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->get_results("

        SELECT pm.meta_value AS user_id, pm.post_id AS order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC, pm.post_id DESC
    ");

    // We format the array by user ID
    foreach($query as $result)
        $results[$result->user_id][] = $result->order_id;

    return $results;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

---

**EXAMPLE USAGE** *just for test to see the raw outputted data*

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(completed_orders_ids_by_costumer_id()); echo '</pre>';
```

You will get something like:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 505
            [0] => 497
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 626
            [1] => 584
            [2] => 483
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 614
            [1] => 598
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 634
        )

    … / … and so on …

)
```

---

> Now in `wp_postmeta` table you will also some other **meta keys** related to **paid orders** that you could use:
>   • `'_paid_date'`
>   • `'_date_paid'`
>   • `'_date_completed'`
>   • `'_completed_date'`
>
> But targeting "completed" order status is just fine

Using that others listed meta keys, you can make your SQL query *(that can replace our first query in the function)*:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value AS user_id, pm.post_id AS order_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm2
    ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    AND pm2.meta_key IN ( '_paid_date', '_paid_date', '_date_completed', '_completed_date' )
    AND pm2.meta_value != ''
    ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC, pm.post_id DESC
");
```

Tested and works too…